# Question regarding App.Config for class library and logging

Tags: c#

I have a class library for which i want to have configuration file.

The purpose of the configuration file is to have the path and other parameters.

Also i wanted to use the Enterprise logging block  in Class library.

Here is my scenario:

1. This is a Class library and will be deployed in GAC
2. Enterprise logging blocks uses app.Config.
3. My calling application which consumes the dll is BizTalk 2010.
4. I don't have permission to modify the BizTalk's application config file

What i am trying to achieve is:

1. My Dll needs to use a configuration file which has many configuration parameters
2. Also as i understand, I need app.config for Enterprise Logging

How can i achieve this? 
Any ideas?

Cheers,
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the machine config. You also have the option to put your configuration in a [separate file](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/EnterpriseLibraryConfigurationSeparateConfigurationFilesApplicationBlocks.aspx) and then reference it from the machine config.

You can also set the values in code but that sorta defeats the purpose of using a config file to begin with.

Comment: Thanks but i wont even have permission to change machine config as well

Answer (score 0):

Modify your class library to open and read config file from specific location.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the calling application's code?

If so, maybe you can [explicitly load the config file as suggested by Marc_s's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544263/net-3-5-dll-using-its-own-config-file)?

Just an idea.