# Design Question - Handling .NET App Config at a DLL level

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, configuration

I have an existing .NET 3.5 based framework that is extended using custom plugins.  In summary plugins implement a common interface and the core framework invokes these via reflection.  The framework works perfectly and all is good, however...

I now have a requirement that requires a plugin that communicates with the WCF service.  At face value this is simple, add a service reference to the plugin, call the client proxy code and off we go.  However...

Due to the way that .NET configuration works the WCF service client configuration should reside within the app.config of the executing application.  In this case this is my plugin invoker application.  The problem with this is that it breaks the plugin "model" as the generic invoker application now has to have plugin specific configuration within it.

So the question is does anybody know of an alternative mechanism for handling the WCF service client configuration without putting it into the core invoker application configuration?

Having done a little hunting around there are mechanisms to allow a DLL [to use its own config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544263/net-3-5-dll-using-its-own-config-file).  The issue here is that I don't have access to the underlining code of the service proxy creation and therefore seemingly can't redirect the config reads.

Comment: I'm probably totally off in understanding the issue, but is it possible to extend the plugin contract to include a method for service initialization? Then have your service-based plugins implement that contract as oppossed to the general one. This would allow you to offload service initialization stuff to the plugin developer without worrying about details of initializing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I seem to have found a solution to the problem here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/10/19/loading-the-wcf-configuration-from-different-files-on-the-client-side.aspx

In summary this allows you to specify a custom configuration file that contains the WCF configuration as it is generated by Visual Studio - this means that the config can be maintained easily.

Having run a couple of quick tests it seems that it works as it should (with a few tweaks here and there (see the comments on the page).

Answer (score 1):

A WCF client's endpoint **can be configured programmatically** as well.

Here's an example that shows how to invoke a WCF service without the need for a configuration file:

```
var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/myservice");
var client = new MyServiceClient(myBinding, myEndpoint);

try
{
    client.MyServiceOperation();
    client.Close();
}
catch
{
    if (client != null)
    {
        client.Abort();
    }
}
```

**Related resources:**

- [ClientBase<TChannel> Constructor (Binding, EndpointAddress)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574927.aspx)

Comment: I did consider this option however it would be beneficial to be able to use WCF configuration and be able to use all the properties etc available.  If I go for programatic bindings etc then I would have to manage all the config myself - it may also break things in future .NET releases.

Comment: If you want to keep the plugin host completely isolated from the implementation details of the external plugins, then your best bet is to to **define a set design guidelines for the plugin authors to follow**. In these guidelines you would then describe how they should handle custom configuration settings, e.g. by having custom configuration files and reading them through the [System.Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.aspx) API.

Comment: Well as the framework and plugin developer the guidelines are kind of implied :) We already have plugins that use there own config files but these currently all use basic app settings or custom config sections.  Problem with the WCF config is I can't find a way to tell the WCF service client constructor to use anything other that the executing application app.config