# Can Dependency DLL have its own config?

Tags: c#, configuration

Having a host process (Host.exe) and a dependency DLL (HostDep.dll) is it possible for the former to use its own config file? Normally you'd have all config values in Host.exe.config, but I want config settings used by HostDep.dll to reside in HostDep.dll.config.  Is it something accomplishable?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544263/net-3-5-dll-using-its-own-config-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594298/c-sharp-dll-config-file

Comment: Thanks guys any chance it can be done w/out using OpenExeConfiguration? - any sort of config routing?